# How can I increase the effectiveness of encryption for storing application settings?

Tags: encryption, application-settings

I am currently using the RC4 algorithm to store application settings and when I observe output it looks easily decodable. The output of strings which start with the same letters appear to be the same.

Short strings lead to short output and longer strings produce longer output.

However I am looking for something that will produce longer output for short strings.

Is there another algorithm that will create more 'scrambled' output even with short strings?

I also want to suffix or prefix the input with some data that I can easily recognize and strip out after decoding to create more randomness on the output.

I have created new code using Rijndael displayed below, but it still suffers from the same lack of variation in the output. I suspect there are some additional parameters required to create more variation in the output, IVs, block padding and all that.

```
unit testform;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, LResources, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, DCPrijndael, DCPsha1;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    edtKeyString: TEdit;
    edtInputText: TEdit;
    edtEncryptedText: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure edtInputTextChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end; 

var
  Form1: TForm1; 

implementation

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.edtInputTextChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  Cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
begin
  Cipher:= TDCP_rijndael.Create(Self);
  Cipher.InitStr(edtKeyString.Text,TDCP_sha1);
  edtEncryptedText.Text := Cipher.EncryptString(edtInputText.Text);
  Cipher.Burn;
  Cipher.Free;
end;

initialization
  {$I testform.lrs}

end.
```

Comment: How are you generating the key you're using to encrypt the data?

Comment: With a stream cypher in xor-mode you should only use a key **once**. It has very similar properties to a one-time-pad. Use a block cypher in an appropriate mode. You should only use a stream cypher if you know what you're doing since they're much easier to get wrong than block cyphers.

Answer (score 1):

RC4 is a stream cipher. You might want to look at a block cipher like AES. Don't forget to use padding, too, e.g. PKCS7.

EDIT: Do *not* add suffix/prefix data in order to "create more randomness". The encryption algorithm will do that for you (unless it's a broken algorithm, in which case choose a different one). At best this is pointless; at worst this is adding a "crib" that will make it easier for someone to attack your encryption.

Comment: What is needed is a random IV. This would also have helped with RC4, although it is not obvious how to use a salt/IV in RC4.

Comment: Using a block cipher answers the "something that will produce longer output for short strings" question. You also need an IV if you are in CBC mode with a block cipher. Stream ciphers don't use IVs at all.

Comment: I guess an alternative solution would be to continue using RC4 but pad each piece of data to some fixed size.

Comment: A random prefix should act very similarly to a random IV with a block-cypher in CBC mode. I don't see how it would weaken the scheme. And I'd add some kind of MAC too.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: The point is that it does not "add more randomness" to the output - good crypto looks random anyway. The IV in CBC mode is to prevent identical cleartext resulting in identical ciphertext but with a stream cipher you don't have that problem anyway (so long as you only use each key once). The main thing is that you should not add complexity needlessly. MAC is a good idea.